Is It Necessary to Check paths[node][-1] == node in Dijkstra's Algorithm Implementation?
I encountered a subtle problem while studying Python on freecodecamp, specifically when implementing Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the shortest path.
Below is the source code I was working with:
python

my_graph = {
    'A': [('B', 5), ('C', 3), ('E', 11)],
    'B': [('A', 5), ('C', 1), ('F', 2)],
    'C': [('A', 3), ('B', 1), ('D', 1), ('E', 5)],
    'D': [('C', 1), ('E', 9), ('F', 3)],
    'E': [('A', 11), ('C', 5), ('D', 9)],
    'F': [('B', 2), ('D', 3)]
}

def shortest_path(graph, start, target=''):
    unvisited = list(graph)
    distances = {node: 0 if node == start else float('inf') for node in graph}
    paths = {node: [] for node in graph}
    paths[start].append(start)
    
    while unvisited:
        current = min(unvisited, key=distances.get)
        for node, distance in graph[current]:
            if distance + distances[current] < distances[node]:
                distances[node] = distance + distances[current]
                if paths[node] and paths[node][-1] == node:       # <<<<< HERE!
                    paths[node] = paths[current][:]
                else:
                    paths[node].extend(paths[current])
                paths[node].append(node)
        unvisited.remove(current)
    
    targets_to_print = [target] if target else graph
    for node in targets_to_print:
        if node == start:
            continue
        print(f'\n{start}-{node} distance: {distances[node]}\nPath: {" -> ".join(paths[node])}')
    
    return distances, paths
    
shortest_path(my_graph, 'A')

The question arises in the if statement on line 21:
if paths[node] and paths[node][-1] == node:
I'm wondering if it's necessary to check whether paths[node][-1] is equal to node, even though I've already checked that paths[node] is not empty.
I've already asked this question to GPT, but the responses were a bit confusing and inconsistent. Could you please clarify whether this check is necessary and why?
I removed the condition and paths[node][-1] == node, but the program continued to function properly. I made sure to check the detailed results every time the path was modified.

Your approach is correct, the first part on line 21 will be true if there are elements in the list paths[node]. The last thing that the program does to paths is to append 'node' at last, hence the last element in line 21 (paths[node][-1] == node) is always true.
"and True" <-- This sentense does not affect the condition at all and it's safe to remove it.
